# Parsing the javascript reduce documentation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In [Mozilla's Reduce docs page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) I found the syntax below:

arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])

The square brackets throw me off.

I have code like this that works:

```
const selectedItems = selectedItemsList.reduce((itemObject, item) => {
  return {
    ...itemObject,
    [item]: this.props.areasList.find(area => area.id === item)
  };
}, {});
```

I do not use square brackets. I provide a callback and an initial value, separated by a comma. Can anyone elaborate on why the doc shows the syntax that it does for reduce? I only figured out the code in this post that I have by looking at other examples.

Comment: it denotes optional parameters

Comment: Spec page? It's a documentation page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square brackets mean that the `initialValue` parameter is optional, i.e. you don't have to provide it. You shouldn't actually place these brackets in your code.